# How can I integrate bBigFont into the next function?

Tags: c++, integration

the problem I have is for a game
I want to mention that I'm not a good programmer in c ++, and this function really gives me the headache.
I try to integrate a multi language system but I get stuck at a function and I can't find a solution
The old function looks like this

```
void SendNotice(const char* c_pszBuf, bool bBigFont)
{
    const DESC_MANAGER::DESC_SET& c_ref_set = DESC_MANAGER::instance().GetClientSet();

    std::for_each(c_ref_set.begin(), c_ref_set.end(), notice_packet_func(c_pszBuf, bBigFont));
}
```

and the new function should look something like this

```
#ifdef __MULTI_LANGUAGE_SYSTEM__
void SendNotice(const char* c_pszBuf, bool bBigFont, ...)
#else
void SendNotice(const char* c_pszBuf, bool bBigFont)
#endif
{
const DESC_MANAGER::DESC_SET& c_ref_set = DESC_MANAGER::instance().GetClientSet();
#ifdef __MULTI_LANGUAGE_SYSTEM__
    if (!c_pszBuf)
        return;

    itertype(c_ref_set) it = c_ref_set.begin();

    while (it != c_ref_set.end())
    {
        LPDESC d = *(it++);

        if (d->GetCharacter())
        {
            const char* c_szLocaleFormat = LC_LOCALE_TEXT(c_pszBuf, d->GetLanguage());

            char szChatBuf[CHAT_MAX_LEN + 1];
            va_list args;

            va_start(args, c_pszBuf);
            int len = vsnprintf(szChatBuf, sizeof(szChatBuf), c_szLocaleFormat, args);
            va_end(args);

            d->GetCharacter()->ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_NOTICE, "%s", szChatBuf);
        }
    }
#else
    std::for_each(c_ref_set.begin(), c_ref_set.end(), notice_packet_func(c_pszBuf, bBigFont));
#endif
}
```

In the new function I have to define **bBigFont** but I don't realize how, can someone correct the function?

Comment: how you even expect to implement multi-language while using `char`,a lot of languages go outside of single-byte strings and unicode string cannot be treated as C null-terminated string?  ANd what do you mean by "define"? It's not clear what it should do.

Comment: I posted the old function above
what I posted, is just to integrate bBigFont
I have to replace
```
std::for_each(c_ref_set.begin(), c_ref_set.end(), notice_packet_func(c_pszBuf, ***bBigFont***));
```

with

```
if (!c_pszBuf)
        return;

        (you can find the whole function upstairs)

}
    }
```